# SSL handshake failed using Ingress way for Kafka created by Strimzi

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, apache-kafka, k3s, strimzi

I have a local k3s Kubernetes cluster created by multipass.

I am trying to set up Kafka using Ingress way based on [this tutorial](https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/05/23/accessing-kafka-part-5/) to make it accessible for clients running outside of Kubernetes.

Here are my steps:

First get my cluster IP by

```
➜ kubectl get nodes
NAME          STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
west-master   Ready    control-plane,master   15m   v1.26.3+k3s1

➜ kubectl get node west-master -o wide
NAME          STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION        INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
west-master   Ready    control-plane,master   16m   v1.26.3+k3s1   192.168.205.5   <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS   5.15.0-67-generic   containerd://1.6.19-k3s1

➜ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://192.168.205.5:6443
CoreDNS is running at https://192.168.205.5:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
Metrics-server is running at https://192.168.205.5:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:metrics-server:https/proxy
```

which is `192.168.205.5` (Is this correct IP address for the one I used in **my-kafka-persistent.yaml** I used in next step?).

Then I deploy my Kafka by:

```bash
kubectl create namespace hm-kafka
kubectl apply --filename="https://strimzi.io/install/latest?namespace=hm-kafka" --namespace=hm-kafka
kubectl apply --filename=my-kafka-persistent.yaml --namespace=hm-kafka
```

**my-kafka-persistent.yaml** (based on [kafka-persistent.yaml](https://strimzi.io/examples/latest/kafka/kafka-persistent.yaml)):

```yaml
---
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: hm-kafka
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.4.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
      - name: external
        port: 9094
        type: ingress
        tls: true
        configuration:
          bootstrap:
            host: kafka-bootstrap.192.168.205.5.nip.io
          brokers:
          - broker: 0
            host: kafka-broker-0.192.168.205.5.nip.io
          - broker: 1
            host: kafka-broker-1.192.168.205.5.nip.io
          - broker: 2
            host: kafka-broker-2.192.168.205.5.nip.io
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      default.replication.factor: 3
      min.insync.replicas: 2
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.4"
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
        - id: 0
          type: persistent-claim
          size: 100Gi
          deleteClaim: false
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 3
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 100Gi
      deleteClaim: false
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
```

After deployment:

Pods

[image]

Services

[image]

Ingresses

[image]

Also, for each Ingress, I can see SSL passthrough in the annotations:

[image]

Then I succeed following the tutorial creating the truststore.

```bash
➜ kubectl get secret hm-kafka-cluster-ca-cert \
  --namespace=hm-kafka \
  --output=jsonpath="{.data.ca\.crt}" \
  | base64 -d \
  > ca.crt

➜ keytool -importcert \
  -trustcacerts \
  -alias root \
  -file ca.crt \
  -keystore kafka-truststore.jks \
  -storepass my_passw0rd \
  -noprompt
Certificate was added to keystore
```

However, when I try to produce data, I met this issue:

```
➜ kafka-console-producer \
  --broker-list kafka-bootstrap.192.168.205.5.nip.io:443 \
  --producer-property security.protocol=SSL \
  --producer-property ssl.truststore.password=my_passw0rd \
  --producer-property ssl.truststore.location=kafka-truststore.jks \
  --topic my-topic
>[2023-04-14 15:57:06,047] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (kafka-bootstrap.192.168.205.5.nip.io/192.168.205.5:443) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-04-14 15:57:06,047] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker kafka-bootstrap.192.168.205.5.nip.io:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-04-14 15:57:06,200] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (kafka-bootstrap.192.168.205.5.nip.io/192.168.205.5:443) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-04-14 15:57:06,201] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker kafka-bootstrap.192.168.205.5.nip.io:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-04-14 15:57:06,691] ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (kafka-bootstrap.192.168.205.5.nip.io/192.168.205.5:443) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-04-14 15:57:06,691] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker kafka-bootstrap.192.168.205.5.nip.io:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Any guide would be appreciate, thanks!

---

### UPDATE 1

Thanks @OneCricketeer pointing the issue!

As I am using **multipass** on macOS, I can provide `INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="server --disable traefik"`, so the updated command to create k3s cluster is:

```bash
multipass launch --name=west-master --cpus=4 --memory=16g --disk=128g
multipass exec west-master -- \
  bash -c 'curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="server --disable traefik" K3S_KUBECONFIG_MODE="644" sh -'
```

I actually switched to Rancher Desktop as it is also using k3s and easy to disable Traefik which can be set up in the UI.

[image]

### UPDATE 2

Regarding how to deploy ingress-nginx and how to resolve another issue "ingress does not contain a valid IngressClass" I met, I posted at [Strimzi Kafka brokers not be created because of "ingress does not contain a valid IngressClass"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76020537/strimzi-kafka-brokers-not-created-because-of-ingress-does-not-contain-a-valid-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k3s uses traefik, not nginx, so those annotations aren't doing anything... The referenced blog assumes you are using nginx instead

Restart your k3s cluster, but provide `--no-deploy-traefik` option, and install nginx ingress controller

Otherwise, you will need to refer to Traefik ingress docs on what matching annotations it will use for SSL passthrough.

Keeping in mind, Kafka is not an HTTP/S service, so you should not be using ports 80/443 to communicate with it.

Comment: Here's a reference using nginx on k3s https://dev.to/sr229/how-to-use-nginx-ingress-controller-in-k3s-2ck2